# Building CorDapps against a non-release branch

Tags: corda

I need some help installing a non-release branch of Corda for doing some testing with the TokenSDK.  I must be doing something wrong because I am getting errors in IntelliJ.

OS: Tested on Windows 10 & Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

I am following the steps from the documentation: [link](https://docs.corda.net/building-against-non-release.html)

Step 1) Clone the Corda Repository:

`git clone https://github.com/corda/corda.git`

Step 2) Checkout the specific branch I need:

`git checkout release/os/4.3`

Step 3) Opening the constants.properties file I see:

`cordaVersion=4.3-SNAPSHOT
gradlePluginsVersion=5.0.4`

Step 4) Clone the Gradle Plugins repository:

`git clone https://github.com/corda/corda-gradle-plugins.git`

Step 5) Checkout the tag listed in the constants.properties file:

`git checkout release/5.0.4`

Step 6) Install the Gradle Plugins locally (run from the corda-gradle-plugins folder):

`gradlew install`

Step 7) Publish Corda to my local Maven repository (run from the corda folder):

`gradlew install`

Step 8) Download the Java template:

`git clone https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-java.git`

Step 9) Open the java template in IntelliJ and setup the Project SDK, import module etc.

Step 10) Open the root build.gradle file and change:

`corda_release_version = '4.1'
corda_gradle_plugins_version = '4.0.45'`

to:

`corda_release_version = '4.3-SNAPSHOT'
corda_gradle_plugins_version = '5.0.4'`

After gradle refreshes I get the following errors:

`No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultPropertyState.convention() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [co.paralleluniverse]
Open File`

"Open File" is a link that takes me to this line in the root build.gradle file:

`apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.quasar-utils'`

More Errors:

`Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [id 'net.corda.plugins.quasar-utils']`

`Caused by: org.gradle.api.reflect.ObjectInstantiationException: Could not create an instance of type net.corda.plugins.QuasarExtension_`

`Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultPropertyState.convention() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [co.paralleluniverse]`

Am I missing a step or doing one incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Corda4.3, Corda has moved onto a quarterly release schedule. I am confident that we will bring the features to the community as soon as possible. Please stay tuned with us at https://www.corda.net/